# What's the best way to keep bad words into database entity?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, widget

I have some web application for placement on external sites. This application is a widget for comments like disqus (disqus.com).

In application each widget it's a entity object with a lot of many attributes.
For instance:

```
@Entity
class Widget {

    private User admin;        //same as owner, administrator, creator

    private String site;       //example.com

    private String providers;  //google_plus,facebook,twitter,lastfm and others

    //... and a lot of many other attributes
}
```

At the now I develop the list of the bad words. This list will be managed by an administrator widget (owner).

For this task I have two ways for implements:

First way:

```
@Entity
class Widget {

    ...
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "bad_words", length = 20)
    private Set<String> badWords= new HashSet<String>();
    ...
}
```

that is keep as relation in second table

Second way:

```
@Entity
class Widget {

    ...
    @Column(name = "bad_words", length = 2000)
    private String badWords;
    ...
}
```

that is keep as string with words splited by some separator, for instance: "fukc,azz,shitt,..."

So the question is what's the best way to keep bad words in the each widgets entity? Case 1, 2 or some thing else?

Comment: on the topic of word filters your approach wont' work, you have to match the words phonetically this is a non-trivial problem to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely Option 1. Option 2 violates [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Think about having all the words concatenated as discuss in the Second Way. A lot of difficulties in querying the table will arise. Also, a lot of awful code for updating/deleting/adding words will appear. You don't want any of this.

Having all the words in a collection (First Way) will permit querying them easily and will make all the CRUD operations simpler.

Comment: And how about that would make the bad words as a table (new entity), and related this entity with widget as ManyToMany (not as ElementCollection)? This will reduce the count of bad words into table of database.

Comment: @user647919 yes, thats possible. it depends on what you need for your application. having a many-to-many will probably require a specific CRUD for the bad words. it's up to your implementation now.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should keep a separate list of bad words, rather than cramming them all in to a single column.

It's cleaner. And there are a *lot* of bad words.

If each widget really needs its own list of bad words, I'd leave it as-is. If the list of bad words is always the same, however, I would not associate them directly with the widget, but maintain the list as a separate entity.

Comment: Do you mean the first way (Set<String> badWords= new HashSet<String>()) ?

Comment: @user647919 Yep, a set, or a list. But this is harder than you think it is--there are a lot of ways to "disguise" bad words, like a$$hole, dikchead, milf, d-bag, etc. Then you have to consider foreign words, like pendejo, ni ma mai pi, and so on. Good luck!